# Firebase dynamic link not opening/launching my installed app

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I recently implemented Firebase dynamic links into my app. But I have a problem with some of Android devices that are directed to the Play store, when pressing the dynamic link, although they have the app installed. (it works fine with other devices such as Nexus 4, Samsung Note 4, etc.)

Is the Firebase dynamic links are not supported by all android devices Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
After further research I found that if I copy and paste the dynamic link to the chrome browser, it is not working also with devices that it work by clicking on the link in apps such as WhatsApp.
So the problem is that chrome doesn't launch the installed app and direct the user to the play store instead. any idea how to fix it?

Thank's!

Comment: I think that the linked answer is not directly related. The linked question has to do with the URL being opened in the browser (i.e. being redirected to a website). This question relates to why it openes the Play Store instead of directly opening the app. After some trial and error here are my findings: The app only launches fine when you actually click the link or if you paste the link in a completely *new* tab of chrome. If you reuuse a already open tab it opens the Play Store. This seems like a bug to me.